# Efficient way of tracking Ordinal data movement over time

Tags: python, pandas

I have some ordinal data column in my dataframe and would like to track how these category goes up or down in the hierarchy over time.

For instance if my dataframe looks like:

```
Date  Animal  OrdinalCategory
Mar     A      Good
Mar     B      Worse
Jun     A      Bad
Jun     B      Worse
Jun     C      Bad
Jun     D      Bad
Sep     B      Bad
Sep     D      Worse
```

I would like to create two new columns to indicate if the Animal is a new entry or has exited in the subsequent quarter.

Similarly I would like to track progress and indicate if the category has improved or Worsened.
So my new df would look like:

```
Date  Animal  OrdinalCategory   EntryExit              Progress
Mar     A      Good            
Mar     B      Worse
Jun     A      Bad             Gone in next            Down from previous
Jun     B      Worse
Jun     C      Bad             New&Gone in next
Jun     D      Bad             New
Sep     B      Bad                                     Up from Previous
Sep     D      Worse                                   Down from Previous
```

Can you advise on the most efficient way to achieve this ?

The ways I have done before and tedious enough is comparing each string (using shift function) and np.where clause to populate the new column. But i find it is clearly inefficient.

Comment: @jezrael Can you help please:)

Comment: Yop, I see it, but really complicated...

Comment: It seems some loop solution is necessary, but because I am not fun of loops I not looking for solution

Comment: oops..even for you !
Better to convert those ordinal categories into numbers ? and then have the difference to indicate progress ? 
And for entryexit : perhaps just check if the animal is present in the previous date and/or future date.

Comment: yeah i wouldnt prefer loops either..
perhaps need to break the problem into multiple parts..

Comment: Yop, agree, it is good idea.

Comment: You wanna volunteer ? :)

Comment: hmmm, I am only hobby programmer :)

Comment: oops ok      :) 
my bad luck

Answer (score 0):

Dealt with this in a slightly different way.

```
ordered_categpry = ['NA', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Worse']
df.OrdinalCategory.astype("category",
  ordered=True,
  categories=ordered_categpry
).cat.codes
```

And for the Entry Exit prob, created two columns to indicate when the animal entered first and when it is appearing the last in the data.

```
df['first_occured']=df['Animal'].map(df[df.OrdinalCategory!="NA"].drop_duplicates(['Animal'],keep='first').set_index(['Animal'])['Date'])


df['last_occured']=df['Animal'].map(df[df.OrdinalCategory!="NA"].drop_duplicates(['Animal'],keep='last').set_index(['Animal'])['Date'])
```