# Pivot table using Pandas, add extra row at the end with subtract calculation

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe df, looks like below:

```
product    price

prod0       10
prod1       20
prod2       30
prod3       40         
cashback    30
```

I want to create a pivot table using panda, where margin will be "GrandTot" and extra row will be there at the end "with cashbak"
how can I get an output like below?

```
col_name     price     GrandTot
Product
prod0         10         10
prod1         20         20
prod2         30         30
prod3         40         40
cashback      30         30
GrandTot      100        100
with cashbak  70         70
```

Comment: There is only one column `price`? So always `GrandTot` is `price` ?

Comment: But without counting cashback.

Comment: Yes, consider that only. I just want to know the last two rows(GrandTot and with cashbak ) will be calculated in the output?

Comment: Correct grand total should be with out calculating the cashback amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `product` to index and add new column by `sum`, also add `GrandTot` row with subtract `cashback`:

```
df = df.set_index('product')
df['GrandTot'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.loc['GrandTot'] = df.sum().sub(df.loc['cashback'], fill_value=0)
df.loc['with cashbak'] = df.loc['GrandTot'].sub(df.loc['cashback'], fill_value=0)

print (df)
              price  GrandTot
product                      
prod0            10        10
prod1            20        20
prod2            30        30
prod3            40        40
cashback         30        30
GrandTot        100       100
with cashbak     70        70
```

But it seems more logic is add total `sum` to `with cashbak`:

```
df = df.set_index('product')
df['GrandTot'] = df.sum(axis=1)
sum = df.sum()
df.loc['GrandTot'] = sum.sub(df.loc['cashback'], fill_value=0)
df.loc['with cashbak'] = sum

print (df)
              price  GrandTot
product                      
prod0            10        10
prod1            20        20
prod2            30        30
prod3            40        40
cashback         30        30
GrandTot        100       100
with cashbak    130       130
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why the following lines are printing an error? (KeyError: 'GrandTot') 
`df_new = pd.pivot_table(df,index='prods',values='price',aggfunc='sum',margins=True,margins_name='GrandTot')`  <- This creates the dataframe with the last row as `GrandTot`, so this works fine.            
`df.loc['GrandTot'] = df.loc['GrandTot'] - df.loc['cashback']` <- This is where I get the KeyError

Comment: @CeliusStingher - hmm, it seems no new column `GrandTot`

Comment: @jezrael : Can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59963431/efficient-way-of-tracking-ordinal-data-movement-over-time :)

Comment: one more quest @jezrael , say for example, I want to make a colour for the columns, price="red" and Grandtot = "yellow" and want to save to into excel file. is it possible?

Comment: @greenking - do you think background colors? Something like [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) ? Can you more specific colors? Do you think all data of column?

Comment: yes @jezrael all the data for a particular column and background color. For example the background color of column "price" and grand total would be red and green respectively accross all values except the last two rows which is "Grandtot" and "with cashbak"

Comment: @greenking - Can you create new question?

Comment: sure, creating a new question